# VBA, need help my code's output takes too long to generate

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a lists of data in a `sheet("DATA")`, in column B I got lists of I.D numbers and in Column C I got lists of names, now in my UserForm when I input an i.d number in `textbox1` then the `combobox2` will populate all the names which is having the same i.d number.

My code works well but my problem is the time of generating `combobox2` lists. I need a way that will make it faster.

Heres my code:

```
Sub cmbo2()
    Dim i as long, lastrow as long
    lastrow = Sheets("DATA").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 to lastrow
        If Sheets("DATA").Cells(i,"B").Value=(Textbox1) Or Sheets("DATA").Cells(i,"B"),Value=Val(Texbox1) Then
            ComboBox2.AddItem Sheets("DATA").Cells(i,"C").Value
        End if
    Next
End sub
```

I'm using a `keycode = 13` enter

```
Private Sub Textbox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        ComboBox2.Clear
        Call cmbo2
        ComboBox2.DropDown
        ComboBox2.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

New sub cmbo2 code

```
Sub cmbo2()
    Dim i as variant

    With worksheets("DATA")
        i = application.Match(CStr(TextBox1),.Columns(2),0)

        If IsError(i) Then _
          i = Application.Match(CLng(TextBox1),.Column(2),0)

        If Not IsError(i) Then _
          ComboBox2.AddItem.Sheets("DATA").Cells(i,"C").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

But there's still a problem. `combobox2` populates only one name even though there's a lot of names in that i.d.
I want to populate `combobox2` with all the names that has the same i.d.
The i.d I'm using is not unique. Every i.d is used by 2 or more names.

Comment: How many rows of data do you have?  How many list entries (generally speaking)?

Comment: A lot, maybe a thousand

Comment: Thousand rows or thousand matches in your list?

Comment: A thousand rows...

Comment: It's only populating one name because the answer you got from Jeeped told you to use `match` instead of looping - but using `.Match` will unfortunately only return the first value with that ID instead of a list of ID's that match the ID. TIm Williams' answer is best option.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a little faster.
Are you missing code to clear previous values from the list?

**EDIT:** fixed and tested

```
Sub cmbo2()
    Dim i As Long, arr

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
        arr = .Range(.Range("B2"), .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)).Value
    End With

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 1) = Me.TextBox1.Text Or _
           arr(i, 1) = Val(Me.TextBox1.Text) Then
            ComboBox2.AddItem arr(i, 2)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it and it gives me run time error 424: object required

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop.

```
Sub cmbo2()
    dim i as variant
    with workSheets("DATA")
        i = application.match(cstr(Textbox1), .columns(2), 0)
        if iserror(i) then _
            i = application.match(clng(Textbox1), .columns(2), 0)

        if not iserror(i) then _
            ComboBox2.AddItem .Cells(i, "C").Value
    end with
End sub
```

Your own code might have benefited from an `Exit For` once a match was found but application.match is always going to be faster than looping through rows.

Comment: Your code gives me a compile error: expected function or variable

Answer (score 0):

### This will populate the combobox once you hit enter in the textbox. It can also be used in a command button if that is preferred. First it filters column B the places the data in a newlocation, and that new range is used for the combobox

Could you possibly have no results when you filter?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Dim LstRw As Long, sh As Worksheet, Frng As Range

    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        s = ActiveSheet.Name
        Set sh = Sheets("Data")

        With sh
            .Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Me.TextBox1
            .Range("Y:Y").Clear
            .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Copy .Range("Y1")    'copy filtered data to another location
            LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row
            Set Frng = .Range("Y1:Y" & LstRw)
            Me.ComboBox1.Clear
            Me.ComboBox1.List = Frng.Value
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

### -

You could also use a combobox instead of the textbox, the combobox would only populate with unique items
If you wanted to go with the a combobox instead of a textbox.
Create a new combobox, lets assume the combobox will be named combobox2
Then in the userform initialize event you can populate the combobox2 when you show the userform, this way you will always select what is actually in column B.
Then you can use the combobox2_change event to populate combobox1.

Here are the two codes.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim cUnique As Collection
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim vNum As Variant

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set Rng = sh.Range("B2:B" & sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set cUnique = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
        cUnique.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
    Next Cell
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each vNum In cUnique
        Me.ComboBox2.AddItem vNum

    Next vNum
End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    Dim LstRw As Long, sh As Worksheet, Frng As Range

    s = ActiveSheet.Name
    Set sh = Sheets("Data")

    With sh
        .Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Me.ComboBox2
        .Range("Y:Y").Clear
        .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Copy .Range("Y1")    'copy filtered data to another location
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Frng = .Range("Y1:Y" & LstRw)
        Me.ComboBox1.Clear
        Me.ComboBox1.List = Frng.Value
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code... I tried it and your idea looks great but it gives me a runtime error 424: object required at the .range("C2:C"...........

Comment: Instead of using textbox1_exit event, i used textbox1_keydown event,  If i press the enter key in textbox1 the combobox2 lists will populate.

Comment: Ill wait for the update of your code...because i can use it to my other projects

Comment: Okay, I thought you had gotten it to work, I will update